# Can I use "when" to replace "how often"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, when

Can I use *when* as a replacement for *how often*? Is it common to use *when* to ask about the frequency of an action?

ex: Question: When do you do the dishes?
Answer: Sometimes I do the dishes.

Comment: Usually not. For example, *"Once a day"* is not a reasonable answer for *"When does the sun set?"*

Comment: Welcome! Please add some example usage to the question.

Comment: Contrast "How often do the trains leave? Four times an hour" and  "When do the trains leave? At 10, 20, 30 and 55 minutes past each hour".

Comment: I read this situation in an English book, but it seems to me that not much "speakable".

Question: When do you do the dishes? Answer: Sometimes I do the dishes.

Comment: Hard to tell without context, but, "When do you do the dishes?" feels like a challenge, a shorthand for 'do you ever?'. "You don't ever do the dishes!" 'Yes, I do.' "When do you do the dishes?" … 'Sometimes…'

Answer (score 1):

No, ***when*** does not have the meaning of ***how often***. *When* points to a point in time, even if that point may be regularly repeated. Also, the present tense of *do* is used here, so it bears the connotation of "usually". I understand the question

> When do you do the dishes?

to mean

> At which moment of the day?

and the natural response would be

> I usually do it straight after every meal.

Comment: Besides “a point in time,” *when* can also point to a set of circumstances. For instance, “When do I  do the dishes? Well, if my wife makes the meal, then doing the dishes is kind of my job.”